# How to check if the number of open braces is equal to the number of close braces?

Tags: javascript, regex

How to check if the number of open braces is equal to the number of close braces using regular expressions?

Here is the code:

```
var expression1 = "count(machineId)+count(toolId)";
var expression2 = "count(machineId)+count(toolId))";
```

These are the 2 expressions, where in the `expression1`, the number of open brackets is equal to number of close brackets and in `expression2`, the number of open brackets is not equal to number of close brackets. I need a regular expression which counts the number of open brackets and close brackets and gives me the alert. I need to check for valid syntax too.

```
if(expression1.......){ // here goes the regular expression
    alert("Matched");
}
else{
    alert("Not matched");
}
```

Comment: Do you also need to account for the order? var expression3 = "count)macineId(+count)toolId(" may be matched but is not valid syntax

Comment: ...as it makes a **huge** difference to whether you can use JavaScript regular expressions for this. ;-)

Comment: Why don't you try Stack?

Comment: Yes, i need to consider the valid syntax too... @Adrian

Comment: @madhu You should have mentioned it in the question from the start.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

```
var expression1 = "count(machineId)+count(toolId)";
var expression2 = "count(machineId)+count(toolId))";

if (matches(expression1)) {
    alert("Matched"); // Triggered!
}
else {
    alert("Not matched");
}

if (matches(expression2)) {
    alert("Matched");
}
else {
    alert("Not matched"); // Triggered!
}

function matches(str) {
    try {
        new Function(str);
        return true;
    }
    catch (e) {
        return !(e instanceof SyntaxError);
    }
}
```

This works because `new Function()` will cause a syntax error if your code is wrong. Catching the error means you can handle it safely and do whatever you want. Another good thing is that it doesn't execute the code, it just parses it. Basically, you're leveraging your task to the browser's parser.

It doesn't use regex, but it does check if your code is valid. Thus, it tells you if the parentheses match.

Comment: No words. That's perfect. +100.

Comment: Good solution, the error scenario returns true though return !(e instanceof SyntaxError);

Comment: @Drew haha true! Some logic missing there :-)

Comment: You can easily implement this using a loop which is O(n). Using a function constructor to simply do parsing is a lot more expensive. 

Checking for matching parenthesis only require the first 2 stages of the compiler (scanner and parser). While that implementation is in C/C++, it is unlikely to be faster than O(n) when dealing with a large N.

Comment: Nice solution though I had the same thought as @voidvector. What is the computational complexity of parsing with `new Function` anyway ?

Comment: Here is a jsperf: http://jsperf.com/function-constructor-vs-old-way Clearly, as long as it's true, the perfs don't matter that much. That said, when exceptions are thrown... clearly, the perf are going down. Well, it's still not as slow as the DOM, but it's not far. In a case of high performance, OP should definitely go with the old (unelegant) way.

Comment: @Ankit why is it so? I'm not *executing* the code, I'm just *interpreting* it to check for syntax errors.

Comment: it's a relative comparison not an absolute comparison that matters.

Comment: If all you care about is whether the parentheses all match up, then don't use this solution.  Suppose all your parentheses match up, but the expressions inside them are not valid code.  In this case, the exception is going to be thrown, and you'll get the wrong result.  This is the correct answer to a completely different question; but the wrong answer to this one.

Answer (score 13):

Task can be simply solved without regexp, just count braces.

```
var a = 'count(machineId)+count())toolId)'
var braces = 0;
for (var i=0, len=a.length; i<len; ++i) {
   switch(a[i]) {
       case '(' : 
          ++braces;
          break;
       case ')' : 
           --braces;
           break;
   }
   if (braces < 0) {    
      alert('error');
      break;
   }
}

if (braces)
    alert('error');
```

Answer (score 5):

If your goal is to check if an expression is valid (it also means its substring that contains only brackets forms a correct bracket sequence), then regexps won't help you.

Regular expressions can only handle so called "[regular languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language)" (though JS regexps maybe somewhat more powerful than their theoretic counterparts, the price of such power is greater complexity) while language of correct bracket sequences isn't regular.

See those [slides](http://www.sm.luth.se/csee/courses/smd/163/lecture4.pdf) — they can give you a glimpse into why regular expressions cannot recognize correct bracket sequence.

Nevertheless, the problem isn't so hard. You should just maintain a stack and go over your string from the left to the right. Every time you meet an opening bracket, you push it to the stack. When you meet a closing bracket, you pop top element of the stack and check if its type matches your one (yes, this algorithm can handle brackets of multiple types). At the end you should just check if the stack is empty.

In case you don't need to handle different types of brackets (you have only '(' and ')', for example) you can just maintain a variable `openBrackets` (essentially it would represent stack's size) and don't let it become negative.

Comment: No, for this problem regex applied in an iterative manner works just fine. See my answer - it is short, fast and accurate.

Comment: @ridgerunner, your approach is out of formal languages theory. In fact, your code is kind of a pushdown automaton and it's quite more powerfull than regexp only. One can parse any programming laguages using regexps to compare strings, but it's totally useless to say that regex works fine in parsing.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (expression1.match(/\(/g).length === expression2.match(/\)/g).length) {
    // is equal
}
```

In order to make it work with strings containing no braces, you may use the following workaround:

```
((expression1.match(/\(/g) || []).length
```

Comment: Note that `))((` is consider true by this code, since only the count is taken into consideration, the order can be any.

Comment: @nhahtdh The OP wants to count the number of brackets but not to check the validity.

Comment: I'm aware of that, just showing an example to make sure the OP really wants this.

Answer (score 3):

If you only care about the **count** why don't you try something like this.

```
if(expression1.split('(').length == expression1.split(')').length) {
  alert('matched');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way to do it:

```js
function validParenNesting(text) {
    var re = /\([^()]*\)/g; // Match innermost matching pair.
    // Strip out matching pairs from the inside out.
    while (text.match(re))
        text = text.replace(re, '');
    // If there are any parens left then no good
    if (text.match(/[()]/))
        return false;
    // Otherwise all parens part of matching pair.
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> 1. "I need to match the no of open braces equal to no of close braces using regular expression"
> 2. "I need to check for the valid syntax too."

If **2** is true, then **1** is also true. So, look for matches for what you know is valid syntax -- in this case: **`{}`**. Execute a loop which removes all valid matches from the "stack" until there are no valid matches left. If what's left at the end is nothing, then it means your argument is 100% valid. If what's left at the end is *something* -- it means the "remainders" didn't pass your validity test, and are thus invalid:

```
var foo = function(str) {
    while(str.match(/{}/g))           // loop while matches of "{}" are found
        str = str.replace(/{}/g, ''); // "slices" matches out of the "stack"
    return !str.match(/({|})/g);      // `false` if invalids remain, otherwise `true`
};

foo('{{{}}}'); // true
foo('{{}}}}}}}}}}{}'); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ...

```
function matchBraces(s) {
  return s.match(/\(/g).length === s.match(/\)/g).length;
}
```

... then, your code for the alerts would be as follows ...

```
if(matchBraces(expression1)) {
    alert("Matched");
} else {
   alert("Not matched");
}
```

Working copy: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/rwj839mw/)**

Answer (score 0):

The following can be applied to find the number of brackets.
However, it does not use RegExp and uses simple logic.

```
var l = 0;
var r = 0;
//Count the number of brackets.
for(var i=0;i<str.length;i++){
  if(str[i]=="("){
    l++;
  }
  else if(str[i]==")"){
    r++;
  }
}
if(l==r){ //The number of opening and closing brackets are equal.
  doSomething();
}
```