# Regex to find incomplete round brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex that can detect incomplete rounded brackets. 
I tried this. `/^(?:(?!\(.*\)))/`
My test string is this `(sample`, then this regex detects incomplete bracket i.e returns result `true`. However if my test string is this `(sample) (another`. Then it returns false.

I have to find for a negated pattern, because if I try to look for simple `/\(*\)/`, then it will detect first complete bracket and return. Now even after trying a negative lookahead, it is failing. Please help me as to where am I going wrong.

P.s. Ok that test string is just too stupid. Here's what I am actually trying to achieve. User will enter a natural query like ((A and B) or (C and D)) or E. This is something that will be used to group up set of rules.

Comment: What is the regex for? Count the number of opening brackets and the number of closed brackets. If they don't match you know what the problem is.

Comment: @NicholasW may or may not include nested brackets

Comment: @Jon, he probably doesnt want to accept `)(` as valid, so counting is too primitive. now, counting by using a stack, pushing `(` and popping `)` would work.

Comment: That's not possible with a regular expression. You need states to model something like that. See Ankit link. That's a quick solution for the problem.

Comment: Yes I can do that, but I will have to loop through string. So to avoid it, I was thinking of using regex.

Comment: Please have a look at edited question

Comment: @chris: Of course, in that case a stack would be fine. Or just a running count of open parens really -- if it ever goes to -1 or terminates at > 0 then you have unmatched parens.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, everyone is responsible. The community is running SO. You are welcome to cast a flag as duplicate.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin: Marking is open to anyone with at least 3K rep, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges).

Comment: this isnt an identical question to the linked one(this one require recursivly nested parenthesis). Also, regarding the top answer in that question, using eval() on user input is hardly a good solution, despite that answer getting 45 votes from people who arent aware of the danger.

Comment: @chris: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13950882/50079) does it with a running count, and it only has 3 votes. Style over substance it seems. ;-)

Comment: @Shades88, if there's a max practical nesting depth that you're willing to accept, you can use pure js regex by making a somewhat repetative looking pattern. Otherwise, you need some code to do this. It's the arbitrarily deep nesting is what js regex doesnt support.

Comment: @Jon, yes, that answer is good :)

Comment: @chris hi, [someone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950704/how-to-count-the-no-of-open-brackets-and-no-of-close-brackets/13950993?noredirect=1#comment24940713_13950993) redirected me here :-). The code I used doesn't evaluate user input, it only "compiles" it. There's no runtime involved. The code I used also checks for nested parens, since it's still valid javascript. OP should be aware that the code doesn't work for `(+)` though, since it's not valid JS syntax. But most examples run just fine. (At least, all the examples shown here and in the other question.) (And yes, it's stylish.)

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

1. You bound your expression to the start of the string by the anchor `^`, so it will only match a opening bracket at the start of the string (and will fail, when it finds another closing bracket.)
2. **If your brackets are nested, it is not possible with JavaScript regex.** <sub>(if they are not nested it could be done)</sub>

Comment: unfortunately there will be nested brackets. So no way out it seems

Answer (score 1):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13951471/1008891), you cannot determine if the parentheses are matching through regex alone. Other answers are available there which solve the problem in various others ways (i.e. without relying exclusively on regex).

Answer (score 1):

As other answers already mentioned, recursive regular expressions are not possible in javascript. Here's a function that returns either `true`, if a string has correctly paired brackets, or the character index where a problem occurs.

```
var nested_brackets = function (test) {
    var left = '(', right = ')';
    var i = 0, n = test.length, tally = 0;
    while (i < n) {
        if (test[i] == left) ++tally;
        else if (test[i] == right) --tally;
        if (tally < 0) break;
        ++i;
    }

    return (i == n && tally == 0) || i;
}
```

Some examples

```
nested_brackets("(A and (B or C))"); // returns true
nested_brackets("(A) and (B)");      // returns true
nested_brackets("(A and (B or C)");  // returns 15
nested_brackets("(A and B)) or C)"); // returns 9
```

Comment: +1 for javascript solution, and that it returns the problem location.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative to using a regex (and the nested bracket issue), [similar to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17216000/592253) by @[kmoerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1925202/kmoerman), but the function returns either `true` or `false` and takes optional arguments so you can test for say `{` and `}`

Javascript

```
function testParenthesisPairs(string /*, openChar, closeChar */ ) {
    var length = string.length,
        i = 0,
        count = 0,
        openChar = arguments[1] || "(",
        closeChar = arguments[2] || ")";

    while (i < length) {
        char = string.charAt(i);

        if (char === openChar) {
            count += 1;
        } else if (char === closeChar) {
            count -= 1;
        }

        if (count < 0) {
            return false;
        }

        i += 1;
    }

    return count === 0;
}

console.log(testParenthesisPairs("()()()()"));
console.log(testParenthesisPairs("()()()()", "(", ")"));
console.log(testParenthesisPairs("()()()("));
console.log(testParenthesisPairs(")()()()"));
console.log(testParenthesisPairs(")(()()()"));
```

Output

true
true
false
false
false

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2Kp5f/)

Update: also similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950704/how-to-count-the-no-of-open-brackets-and-no-of-close-brackets/13950882#13950882) by @[Damask](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1767378/damask) as pointed to by @[Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/50079/jon) in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

This might be an offhand answer, and I think it would probably depend on the expected kind of input...

```
\([^\)]*$
```

That one will look for any instance of a "(", that does NOT have a ")" between it and the end of the file/line. So if this returns true, you can point the user to the index of the match. If your parentheses format does not support nesting (which, as stema said, it should *not* if you're trying to handle it with just Regex) then you could do something similar for open-parentheses. I would have put that in my sample, but for some reason the syntax of "EOF *or* (" was failing my memory on regexpal.com...)

Comment: this doesnt handle nesting right?

Comment: Nope. Just about the only way to handle nesting would be with a lot of repetition, and a hard limit on the number of levels. So the quickest answer is: No, Regex can't handle nesting. It just doesn't support looping in the required ways. A simple, small regex COULD at least help you find the nesting markers, so that you can parse the nesting in a more programmatic way, but it's going to take some manual work. If it's only parentheses, it sounds quite doable.