# How to use a regular expression for checking if comment is closed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, comments

How can I use a regular expression in javascript for checking if a comment is closed in a javascript file?

Comment: You can't check with a regex if brackets are balanced as that depends on the content between the brackets A parser is needed for that. But counting brackets is easy. And if what you want to know is if your code compiles, then it's easy too.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950704/how-to-count-the-no-of-open-brackets-and-no-of-close-brackets

Comment: Could you expand on your circumstances? Regular expressions for code validation is generally a bad idea.

Comment: You can't.  You'd need a full JS grammar parser.  For example, what happens if there's an open bracket inside a string?

Comment: I don't think regular expression is a good method of doing that.

Comment: @KevalDoshi As the old joke goes - I had a parsing problem so I decided to use regexes - now I've got two problems...  ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to use regular expressions for checking parenthesis. 
In order to check if brackets or comment (e.g. /*..*/) are closed, you have to iterate over a string, count the number of opening brackets, and of closing brackets, and to compare.

Example:

```
function check(str)
{
    var paranCount = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
    {
        if (str[i] == '[')
            paranCount++;

        else if (str[i] == ']')
            paranCount--;

        if (paranCount < 0) return false;
    }
    return !paranCount;
}
```

**Note:** This only applies to code pieces that do not contain string (for example), though the inline string "asfasdf[[[" is legal inside the code, yet this function will not deem it so.
With the absence of other limitations to the code, you should use a parser library/file, or use the above function as a basis for writing one yourself.

Comment: There are easier ways to count. And that doesn't tell if they're balanced.

Comment: remember that it is not as simple as EZSlaver suggets, a ][ would also be valid with this algorhythm. You need to check positions also.

Comment: Isn't there an easier way?