# Regex in Javascript to find incomplete items that begin and end with brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to [use regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to find any incomplete things that begin with `{{`.

I've tried to check for any places in the string that begin with `{{` and have a-Z after it but haven't been ended (`}}`). What I'm trying always returns null.

```
string = 'Hello {{name}}, you are {{a';
console.log(string.match(/^({{)?[a-z]:[A-Z]$/g));
```

My expected output would be `{{a` in this case because `{{name}}` is complete. Any help really appreciated.

The only things it will have between it is `.` ie: `{{name.forename}}` `{{name.lastname}}`

Comment: Try using "best regex trick", `/{{\w+}}|({{\w*)/g` and grab Group 1 values. The regex might need adjusting depending on what can be between `{{` and `}}`.

Comment: This question already answered here; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13950704/how-to-check-if-the-number-of-open-braces-is-equal-to-the-number-of-close-braces

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew - This is working great but `match` only returns an array of all the things found right? How would I only get group 1 values?

Comment: `Array.from(text.matchAll(/{{\w+}}|({{\w*)/g), x => x[1]).filter(Boolean)`

Comment: Thank-you so much! This is perfect, I really appreciate it. I couldn't wrap my head around what I need to check for @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: So, it looks like you will only have lettes, digits or underscores in between the double curly braces, right? Please add this requirement to the question, else, it sounds unclear.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I've updated the question to contain this information

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the ["best regex trick ever"](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick), in this case, match all word char chunks between double curly braces or match **and capture** any `{{` followed with zero or more word chars:

```js
Array.from(text.matchAll(/{{\w+(?:\.\w+)*}}|({{(?:\w+(?:\.\w+)*)?)/g), x => x[1]).filter(Boolean)
```

Here,

- `{{\w+(?:\.\w+)*}}` - `{{`, one or more word chars, zero or more sequences of a `.` and one or more word chars, `}}`
- `|` - or
- `({{(?:\w+(?:\.\w+)*)?)` - Group 1: `{{` and an optional occurrence of one or more word chars and zero or more sequences of a `.` and one or more word chars.

Comment: Thanks for your response, did you get a chance to check for the full-stop? Really appreciated.

Comment: @Jaquarh I modified the regex in the answer.